# how to get the previous task name in activiti workflow

Tags: activiti

Actually i want to use the previous task name in current task so how to get the previous task name in current task in  activiti. If any one knows could you help me?

eg:TASK1==>TASK2==>TASK3

i want to use the task1 name in task2 and task2 name in task1.

Comment: what kind of task are?
JavaTask? implemented by you?
if so:
- you can probably get the model (somehow) and parse it.
- you can create a variable in each task and read in the following

Comment: I am using the user task then how to i parse and get the name of the task

Comment: Why not use a task (or execution) listener to save the last task name/id as a process variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from your current Process Instance:

```
@Service
public class SomeWorkflowService {

    @Autowired
    HistoryService historyService;

    @Autowired
    TaskService taskService;

    public Map<String, Object> currentTaskService(String currentTaskId) {
        Map<String, Object> taskMap = new HashMap<>();
        Task currentTask = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskId(currentTaskId).singleResult();
        HistoricTaskInstance previousTask = findPreviousTask(currentTask.getProcessInstanceId());

        taskMap.put("Current task name: ", currentTask.getName());
        taskMap.put("Previous task name: ", previousTask.getName());

        return taskMap;
    }

    // Order tasks by end date and get the latest
    public HistoricTaskInstance findPreviousTask(String processInstanceId) {
        return historyService.createHistoricTaskInstanceQuery().
                processInstanceId(processInstanceId).orderByHistoricTaskInstanceEndTime().desc().list().get(0);
    }

}
```

There maybe some issues with this kind of simple algorithm. For example, I have multiple subprocesses in application, or there may be parallely executed tasks, then I'm using more complex algorithm to find previous task.