# How to Get Current and Previous Task name in Activiti workflow

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

We are using Spring Boot and Activiti for process management. How do we get the current and previous task name. We would like to keep track of the tasks.

The response below looked promising though it requires currentTaskId to the details. Not sure how to get the currentTaskId

[how to get the previous task name in activiti workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652175/how-to-get-the-previous-task-name-in-activiti-workflow)

Thanks

Comment: which  version of acitiviti are you using? Enterprise or community?

Comment: Community Edition 5.22                                                               `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
   <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
   <version>5.22.0</version>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the Historic Task query and order by completed timestamp.
Once you have the task, you can get the associated Activity ID/Name.

Obviously this breaks if you have parallel flow.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

To get the current Task name. create a taskQuery like -

```
delegateExecution.getEngineServices().getTaskService().createTaskQuery().active();
```

this will give you active tasks.

Do same with historic tasks service for finished() tasks. order them by date and select the last one to complete.

This will help you in getting the delegateExecution - [docs](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#serviceTaskCallActivitiService)

Comment: Thank you. How do you initiate `delegateExecution`? Do you have a more complete example where `delegateExecution` is defined/initialized.